# How to migrate/backup all remote branches

Tags: magento2, migration, magento-cloud, github, bitbucket

Steps as follows:

```
$ magento-cloud project:get e7s9kiwfapxcy
$ cd cloned-directory
$ git branch -a
```

Output:

```
* master
remotes/magento/HEAD -> magento/master
remotes/magento/jcollins
remotes/magento/jcollins-child
remotes/magento/master
```

I created a new private repository in Bitbucket
[image: I created a new private repository in Bitbucket]

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:justincoll/magento.git
```

Finally, I attempt to push all remote branches

```
git push -u origin --all
```

**Result:** Only master is pushed

Answer (score 0):

**step 1: (enter in cli)**

```
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v master `; do git checkout --track $remote ; done
```

**step 2: (enter in cli)**

```
git push -u origin --all
```